# verb-casual ような (possible translation)

Tags: grammar, auxiliaries

> 東都大学の国際交流クラブでは、外国人と日本人が一緒に楽しめる**ような**行事を企画したり紹介したりしている。

How should I translate this ような? The only possible translation to me is "in order that".. am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `ような` is to mean `sort of` or `kind of`. So the sentence could be translated like this (without context taken into consideration):

> At the Tokyo University International Cultural Exchange club, we are doing things like planning and introducing **the kinds of events** (or **a kind of event**) where foreigners and Japanese people can have fun together.